# How to display void function below input?

Tags: php, html

I  make a form validation and I want to that function display errors below input. Now the function display errors in top site. I don't know where is problem. Errors should display after  click submit button.

```js
 class UserValidation{
        private $data;
        private $errors = '';
        public function __construct($data)
        {
            $this->data = $data;
        }
   public function validateName()
    {
        $val = trim($this->data['first_name']);
        
        if(empty($val))
        {
            return $this->errors = "Empty field";
        }
        else if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z-0-9]{3,12}$/', $val))
        {
            return $this->errors = "Wrong first name";
        }
        
    }
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $validation = new UserValidation($_POST);
        $error = $validation->validate_First_Name();    
    }
```

```html
">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-xl-12 text-light">
                <label>Login</label>
                <input type="text" name="first_name"  class="form-control">
                <div class="error">
                    <?php echo $error ?? ''  ?>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: One tip: don't use exceptions for validation. Wrong input is not exceptional, it's an ordinary occurrence. If there's an error, just return the error string.

Comment: haha Someone said me :
You combine validation with error presentation Validation methods should return void, and in case of failure, throw an appropriate exception that you catch and handle in the layer above. The current approach only introduces unnecessary state for your class ($ errors property). and now who has right ?

Comment: Validation should not throw exceptions (the name itself should give you a hint, it's exceptional, as in something out of the ordinary has happened - invalid form input is hardly out of the ordinary). Validation methods should ideally return boolean values (either something is valid, or it isn't). And whoever told you that what you currently have separates presentation from validation is wrong - you are defining the error that you will *present* inside your exception.

Comment: I modifield my function. Can you say if this correct now ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton of different ways to do form validation. What you're doing is overly complicated, and as @El_Vanja stated, you shouldn't be throwing exceptions unless something important happens, and incorrectly entering info into a form is extremely common and is to be expected. When validating a form, all you really need to return is the error message.

Edit: this is definitely not production ready as there are plenty of missing parts; this is just an example to give you some ideas regarding validation.

This also puts your error messages below the submit button; which I don't recommend doing as they could be missed if out of the viewport.

```php
<?php

class UserValidation {
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        # define our errors array
        $this->errors = [];
    }
    
    # returns any error messages in the errors array
    public function errors() {
        return $this->errors;
    }
    
    public function validate($key, $value)
    {
        # 'clean' the input
        $val = strip_tags(trim($value));
        
        # only validate if it's not the submit button
        if($key == 'submit')
        {
            if($val == '') {
                $this->errors[$key] = $key . ' can not be empty';
            }
            
            # this is a bad idea as people have apostrophes, etc. in their names
            if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z-0-9]{3,12}$/', $val)) {
                $this->errors[$key] = $key . ' can only contain letters and numbers';
            }
            
            # perform other validation rules here...
        }
        
        return $value;
    }
}

    $v = new UserValidation();
    
    # check if the form was posted using $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        # loop through the $_POST array
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            # run each form field through the validate function
            $v->validate($key, $value);
        }
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <form action="index.php" method="post">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Login</label>
                        <input type="text" name="first_name"  class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <?php
                        # loop through the errors array and print each error
                        foreach($v->errors() as $error) {
                            echo '<span class="text-danger">'.$error.'</span><br>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```